# mysqli_prepare being skipped

Tags: php, sql

So I've copied a sign-up form and login form from [TutorialRepublic](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php) and when it didn't work I added some alerts to figure out what bit of code was not being run.

I ended up finding out that the `mysqli_prepare` portion was being completely skipped over:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM acccounts WHERE username = ?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('yes');</script>";

        // Set parameters
        $param_username = $username;

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Store result
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

            // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                // Bind result variables
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                    if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                        // Password is correct, so start a new session
                        session_start();

                        // Store data in session variables
                        $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                        $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            

                        // Redirect user to welcome page
                        header("location: index.php");
                    } else{
                        // Display an error message if password is not valid
                        $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                    }
                }
            } else{
                // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
            }
            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('error');</script>";
    }
```

I know it's not the best to just take someone elses tutorial code and use it word for word, but I really just need this done. I'm pretty new to both PHP and MySQL, so I have no idea where to even begin trying to debug.

Comment: Shouldn't `pfp/DEFAULT/DEFAULT_$pfp_id.png` be in quotes? Or set to a variable and added as another parameter. At the moment `mysqli_prepare` is probably returning false, thus going into the `else`.

Comment: You should get familiar with the [mysqli_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) function. Use it  to properly debug your queries (use it in your `else`-block). It's most likely the issue that @Jonnix already pointed out.

Comment: @Jonnix that did solve that. However, I am having a similar problem with the code I have just edited in. Instead of making a new question, I figured I'd try to get it all in the same question. This time, it isn't quotes that's making the error. I could really use your help!

Comment: Additionally to checking for errors, you should start writing more modular code. This already looks like a mess and you've just started working on it - maybe you want to check out a PHP framework that keeps database access, session handling, and other components a bit more seperated?

Comment: Have a read of @MagnusEriksson's comment and provide the output.

Comment: @Jonnix  Wow that solved everything. Thanks, if you put your answer in an actual answer I'll check it as the solution.

Comment: Will leave it, you can add an answer yourself if you wish, but my comment wouldn't make sense with your updated question :)

Comment: Please don't edit your question after you've solved the issue. If you do, the comments and potential existing answers won't make any sense for future visitors. Changing the question is basically moving the goal post and not allowing others to take a part of the first solution. If you have another question (even if it's similar), post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so essentially I just had to debug better. After help from two users in the comments, I was able to track down the errors.

I had already made and `else` statement for the alert to say that the `mysqli_prepare` had been skipped. In that `else` statement, I should have added `echo mysqli_error ($link);` as that will output the error info.